# can't save data, when create new data by same category

Tags: php, laravel-5, sum, laravel-query-builder, laravel-5.7

### Model

> error : 
>   "Array to string conversion (SQL: update `spent_times` set `updated_at` = 2018-10-23 09:16:43, `spent_time` = 16, `percentage` = 70, `task_category` = testing where `id` = 1) ◀"

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today();

    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{
        $new_spent_time = SpentTime::first();
        $task_category = $new_spent_time->task_category;
        $new_spent_time->spent_time = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_spent_time', $new_spent_time->daily_spent_time , $fromDate);
        $new_spent_time['spent_time'] = $new_spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $new_spent_time->percentage = $new_spent_time::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_percentage', $new_spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
        $new_spent_time['percentage'] = $new_spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
        $new_spent_time->save();
        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

> and why is it only the first ID?

Comment: first ID of what? Please clarify what you're talking about. As for the error, it means somewhere you're trying to print an array inside a string, which isn't a logical thing to do. But we don't know which of your variables are arrays.

Comment: `$new_spent_time = SpentTime::first();' id from table spent_times

Comment: it is only first id because you get it using `SpentTime::first();` and it is being updated

Comment: @LeenaPatel does that affect when doing save?

Comment: yes you dont need to use `save()` when you are already using `update()`

Comment: can create new data, but can't calculated data, when create new same category. maybe the error is in the else function section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update answer

### Model

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();
    $task_category = $spent_time->task_category;

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{
        $spent_time['spent_time'] = $spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $spent_time['percentage'] = $spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```